# Using wildcards for -group or -user with find command

Tags: bash, find, wildcards

I'm trying to find owners of files on the system that all start with a specific name, for example

```
[unu@here findtest]$ find . -ls
17295583    0 drwxrwxr-x   2 unu      unu            74 Mar 28 03:14 .
17295584    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 br_asd1  br_asd1         0 Mar 28 03:13 ./test1
17295585    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 br_asd2  br_asd2         0 Mar 28 03:13 ./test2
17295586    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 unu      unu             0 Mar 28 03:13 ./test33
17295587    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 br_bfg1  br_bfg1         0 Mar 28 03:14 ./test11
17295588    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 unu      unu             0 Mar 28 03:14 ./test22
```

I need find to only get files owned by users whose name starts with "br_".

So what I tried was

```
[unu@here findtest]$ find . -user "br_*" -ls
find: ‘br_*’ is not the name of a known user
```

Now a method I found that works is using awk, but I have certain problems with this method and it's not really usable for what I'm trying:

```
[unu@here findtest]$ find . -ls|awk '{if ($5 ~ "br_"||$6 ~ "br_") print $0}'
17295584    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 br_asd1  br_asd1         0 Mar 28 03:13 ./test1
17295585    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 br_asd2  br_asd2         0 Mar 28 03:13 ./test2
17295587    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 br_bfg1  br_bfg1         0 Mar 28 03:14 ./test11
```

Is there a way to add wildcards to the `-user` or `-group` options of find?

Comment: With `getent passwd` get a list of users which match `br_.*` and build a list like: `--user br_asd1 --user br_asd2 --user br_bfg1` for `find` command.

Comment: GNU `find` does not have options to pass wildcards for `-user` and `-group` fields. One way would be to use GNU coreutils `stat` and use the `%U` quantifier to get the owner name. Do something like `for file in *; do     [ -f "$file" ] || continue;     owner=$(stat -c '%U' "$file");     if [[ "$owner" =~ ^br.* ]]; then         echo "$file";     fi; done`

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing for `bash` you can use an array to hold the set of users and another array to generate the corresponding syntax for `find` to match those users:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The beginning of the userids we need to match
match=br

# Find the matching set of users
users=($(
    getent passwd |
    awk -F: -vm="$match" 'BEGIN { re = "^" m } $1 ~ re {print $1}'
))

# Build the list of users ("find ( -user XX -o -user YY -o user ZZ ) ...")
finds=()
for user in "${users[@]}"
do
    finds+=('-o' '-user' "$user")
done
[[ ${#finds[@]} -gt 0 ]] && finds=('(' "${finds[@]:1}" ')')

# Execute the find command with the set of users
find . "${finds[@]}" -ls
```

As ever, you can prefix the `find` command with something like `echo` to see what would be executed. (Or you could run with `bash -x` to enable line-by-line debug reporting.)

Comment: Instead of the test in each iteration of that loop, you could just use `"${finds[@]:1}"` when calling `find` to ignore that first `-o` in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is just a listing, I would go for a good old `grep` over `find`’s output. It would be slower, but much less typing.

At the very basic you might try this, for your example case:

```bsh
find -printf '%u %p\n' | egrep '^br_'
```

This gives you the list of files owned by users `br_*`, shown with username and filename on each line.

You might then expand the output by fiddling the `-printf` format string.

For instance, to make it resemble more an `ls` output:

```bsh
find -printf '%-8.8u %-8.8g %M %8s %t %p\n' | egrep '^br_'
```

The important thing to keep the command line as short as possible is to place the username at the very beginning, so that the `egrep`’s part can be kept short like that.

To see all that you can specify in the format string, go [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), then search for `-printf format`.

Be careful though that if your files have newlines in their names then this solution might have problems in showing them.